# "Attribute" node in shader editor: Problem using attribute "Position"

Tags: shader-nodes

[image]Hello everyone.
Since I can find almost nothing updated about the "Attribute" node of the shader editor I am trying to test it a bit.
I wanted to try using the "Position" attribute as seen in the attached image.
In theory with this set of nodes, it should create a gradient of the "cube" mesh material that changes as you place the cube in relation to the X axis
In reality nothing happens, even though in theory reading the instructions it would look right.
The color of the cube just stays black and that's it as if the attribute node doesn't read position changes of the X value at all
What can this depend on?
I have similar concept problems with almost all the various attributes as well, except for the UV one, which is the only one I can get to work.
What problems do you think there are? Blender bugs? procedural errors I'm making?
I have done dozens of trials of all kinds and can find no solution.
Thanks

Comment: Well you're using "Position", not "position", but either way, I don't think "position" is a real attribute, ie. something that shows up in the Attributes panel of the Mesh tab of the Properties editor. If you want the position, you can get it with the Texture Coordinate or Vector Transform node instead (be mindful of what space it's in).

Comment: ok thank you. I also tried using attributes from the manual's list, such as flame and others. But they don't display anything for me. Let's say that basically apart from the attributes customized with vertex paint all the others don't show up, do you know why?